# Add tag before each generated tag | javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I want to add this piece of tag before each and after the  tag. But it adds a new tag next to another. Help me out.
Thanks in advance.

```
<div class="lap-time"><h2>Laps</h2></div>
```

```
document.getElementsByClassName("lap-time")[0].innerHTML += 
               "<p>"+('0' + hour).slice(-2) + ":" + ('0' + minute).slice(-2) + 
               ":" + ('0' + secend).slice(-2)+"</p>";
```

Comment: what is the required result - your description is unclear and your code simply appends to innerHTML - i.e. what does *before each and after the tag* even mean

Comment: Maybe have a look at  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML

Answer (score 0):

Use back ticks when passing HTML with JavaSript. Here is how :

```js
 document.getElementsByClassName("lap-time")[0].innerHTML +=` 
               <p> ${('0' + hour).slice(-2) } : ${('0' + minute).slice(-2)}  
               : ${ ('0' + secend).slice(-2)} </p>`;
```